# How to make skinned Title Bar in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, titlebar

On PrimeFaces showcase page there is a simple title bar which fits in the actual theme. I mean the "Welcome to PrimeFaces showcase" text on this page: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf

This is not a button nor any kind of responsive control, just a themed textbox or title bar.

I've searched a lot but I was not able to find a simple <p:  > component which can generate this kind of result.

Can anybody help me, how to make such an element in PrimeFaces?

Comment: Have you succeeded in making a nice `title bar`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you can find the xhtml code for the welcome page - `home.xhtml(home.jsf)` : http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/webapp/ui/home.xhtml?r=5567

As you can see there, the 'title bar' is just a simple `<h1>` tag with some css:

```
<h1 class="title ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Welcome to PrimeFaces ShowCase</h1>
```

There you can find the entire primefaces website/project, and the CSS files as well, but it's better to implement your CSS...

Comment: I hoped that it could be made easily by a p: tag. With h1 tag I had to add some more style declaration (padding and font-size), but this solution is also perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @GregTom No problem, I'm always here trying to provide the best Primefaces answers to any problem...

Comment: It would become much simpler once we have true css style inheritance (on the style, not the elements), as once we start copying styles from primefaces in our own style declarations, we become theme dependent/harcoded. Probably can make this also simpler with the use of a css preprocessor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<p:toolbar>` tag for it.
Though its main usage lies in grouping together several content, But it does give the effect of a Title Bar you are looking for.

```
<p:toolbar>
   <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
       <p:outputLabel value="Welcome!!" />
   </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```

You can surround the `<p:outputLabel>` tag with other tags like `<h1>`, `<p>` with CSS to give more effect.